# Why does Excel return #NAME? from a function call

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I simply want the function to return the URL from hyperlinked text in a cell.
Found a solution:

```
Public Function GetAddress(HyperlinkCell As Range)
'GetAddress = Replace(HyperlinkCell.Hyperlinks(1).Address, "URL:", "")
Debug.Print ("Function was called on " + HyperlinkCell)
End Function
```

However, not even the Debug is being called.

The workbook is Macro Enabled and has all access under Trust.

Macros work fine, so what does it mean that functions are not working in my Spreadsheet?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Function is working fine, The #NAME? error occurs when Excel does not recognize text in a formula. Like =GETADDRES() will return #NAME error as excel was not able to recognize the function.

Comment: I call the function in another cell. E.G. =GetAddress(E13)

Comment: May I see your file?

Comment: Is any of your other module named `GetAddress`

Comment: No other macros or modules with the name GetAddress.
Do you want to see a screenshot of the file?

Comment: No I actually want to check your VBA editor. If you want, you can delete all sensitive info from your worksheets and then share the file?

Comment: Your function is in Sheet4 and not a module.  or is it in module 6 and sheet 4 is just highlighted?

Comment: @SiddharthRout: You hit the nail on the head. The code is in Sheet4 — see the title bar at the top of the screenshot. OP shout put it in module. You should undelete your answer!

Comment: I had the Function in Module6. I moved it to Sheet 4 after your feedback. How do you want to get the file. Nothing sensitive in it at this point.

Comment: It doesn't seem to matter where I put the code, so at this point I am flailing blindly. What is the standard for user created functions? Where should they reside? The function doesn't even appear in autoselect.

Comment: Move it to a module.

Comment: `I had the Function in Module6. I moved it to Sheet 4 after your feedback.` What feedback? I never said to put it in a sheet code area :)

Comment: I deduced that I had not placed it properly.

Comment: It is in a module. it was from the beginning.
Does it matter which one, given that I have 6?
Is there a standard protocol for function placement versus Macro placement?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have not pasted the code in the module and hence excel is not able to recognize that name. You have to paste the code in a module. Same goes for other UDF.

[image]

Comment: I have Module1 - 6. It is in Module6